# cd_dynamic_conf in DXA 2.0

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0, dynamic

In DXA 1.x versions, we used `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` to define all the domains and websites that we have and map it to the Publication ID.

Now, we are starting our first project in DXA 2.0 and SDL Web 8.5 and we don't see if we need `cd_dynamic_conf` to do this mapping or now is managed in other part.

Where is managed the mapping of website (language) and Publication ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not a matter of DXA 1.x or 2.x, but the use of SDL Web 8.5 with the use of microservices that changes the configuration of the `cd_dynamic_conf` file.

Now these configuration are managed in the "`content microservice`" (live environment) or "`session`" and "`preview microservices`" (staging with xpm environment)

Comment: Thanks, Raul. Is there any post or something similar where is explained.?I tried to understand it using the SDL documentation but is generic and I prefer if I can see with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the way content is published and read has changed in SDL Web 8.5. understanding Topology Manager is where there likely is a change. DXA has not really changed as much in this regard